# Shorten the time of Qt make process

Tags: qt, build, makefile

I executed command make after correctly passed all steps, and it takes to long to build all that libraries and tools, is it possible to shorten that time? For example to throw out uneccessary libraries and tools? It looks that make time goes to infinity...

Comment: Qt has a lot of [configuration](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/configure-options.html) options, read the documentation, read the output of `configure --help`. Your question is too broad for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running make with parallel processes:

```
make -jN
```

Where N is the number of parallel processes you want, perhaps the number of CPUs of your computer